# How to install Azure module in IBM Data Science Experience

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx

I'm trying to import Azure data into DSx. I get an error when I try to import the module. When I use the command "from azure.storage.blob import BlobService" in DSx, it tells me that there's no module with that name. Do I have to do some further setup in DSx to access this module?

Answer (score 3):

Please install the azure package by running following command in your notebook:-

`!pip install azure`

then run this to import your library

`from azure.storage.blob import BlobService`

Please also refer to this article for different ways of installing libraries:-
http://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/importing-libraries.html

Thanks,
Charles.